# Flutter Scrollable Stack with Image on top and container below overlapping with circular border

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to build a screen that looks similar to the following:

[image]

The main functionality I am looking for is that:

1. It is scrollable
2. There is an image in the top half of the screen
3. Below the image is a container with other information in it. The top of the container should overlap the bottom of the image and have rounded borders.

Would any one be able to help me with this. I've been trying stacks, with positioned container and images within singlechildscroll views but not getting anywhere at all right now.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Many thanks

Comment: Is there animation involved when you scroll or layout change?

Comment: No, there is no animation required. Just the ability to scroll up and down. Actually, there are only two elements, an image at the top and then a container. The thing I can't work out is how to get them together with the top of the container overlaying the bottom of the image, so It sits on top.

Comment: Did you get a chance to solve this?